# Update Collection based on input on view

Tags: c#, razor

I am writing a page that allows the user to input values into a text box that is then added to a collection.

**There are 2 loops:**

1. Loop 1 - OrderLines (There can multiple events in the basket each
   has 1 OrderLine)
2. Loop 2 - DelegatesList (there can be multiple FirstName etc but it is unique to 1 OrderLine)

What needs to happen is when they click the UpdateAction button the form passes over the DelegatesList[x] values (x being the list of delegates to the unique OrderLine) over to a controller. The controller then needs to update the OrderLines.DelegatesList collection for the related Orderline with all rows of the DelegatesList from the view (x list).

I understand the logic but I am struggling to get my head around how I carry the values into the controller and then update the collection in a loop on the controller. Any help is greatly appreciated

**View:**

```
@model TSW.Web.ViewModels.Partial.BasketSummary
@using (@Html.BeginUmbracoForm<BasketPageSurfaceController>
  ("Update"))   

<article id="basket-item-delegate__main" class="basket-item-delegate__main" data-id="@i">
            <div class="basket__items">
                <div class="basket-item-delegate">
                    @for (int x = 0; x < @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].Quantity; x++)
                    {
                        var y = x + 1;
                    <div class="basket-item-delegate-list">
                        <h4>Delegate @y</h4>

                        <div class="basket-item-delegate__input-cell">
                            <h6>First Name:</h6>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList[x].FirstName)
                        </div>

                        <div class="basket-item-delegate__input-cell">
                            <h6>Last Name:</h6>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList[x].LastName)
                        </div>

                        <div class="basket-item-delegate__input-cell">
                            <h6>Email</h6>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList[x].Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                     <nav class="basket-item-delegate__buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="UpdateAction" value="Add Delegates" class="basket-item-delegate__button button" />
                     </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
```

**Basket Summary VM:**

```
 public class BasketSummary
{

    public Basket CustomerBasket { get; set; }
    public List<Event> BasketEvents { get; set; }
    public LinkItem CheckoutPage { get; set; }
    public LinkItem DelegatePage { get; set; }
    public JObject ECommerceSummary { get; set; }
    public Event OrderEvent(int eventId)
    {
        return BasketEvents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == eventId);
    }

}
```

**OrderLine VM:**

```
public class OrderLine
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be a number")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDelegate> DelegatesList { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderDelegate VM:**

```
public class OrderDelegate
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT: Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Basket()
    {
        var model = Mapper.Map<BasketVM>(CurrentContent);
        model.BasketSummary.CustomerBasket = await TransactionLibrary.GetBasketAsync();
        model.BasketSummary.CustomerBasket.AllowBasketUpdates = true;
        model.BasketSummary.BasketEvents = new List<Event>();

        model.InnerPageHeader.ShowHeading = true;
        model.InnerPageHeader.Title = model.PageTitle;

        await model.BasketSummary.CustomerBasket.OrderLines.ForEachAsync(async dt =>
        {
            var eventDetail = await _eventService.GetEvent(dt.EventId);
            model.BasketSummary.BasketEvents.Add(eventDetail);
            var delegatelist = new List<OrderDelegate>
        });

        model.BasketSummary.CheckoutPage = Mapper.Map<LinkItem>(_pageFactory.GetCurrentHomepage().CheckoutPage);

        if (Session["ErrorList"] != null)
        {
            var errorList = Session["ErrorList"] as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>>;
            foreach (var modelState in errorList)
            {
                ModelState.Add(modelState);
            }
            Session.Remove("ErrorList");
        }

        return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Your view is not clear. Your `@for (int x = 0; x < @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].Quantity; x++)` does not make sense. 1. Where does the value of `[i]` come from? (you need nested `for` loops) 2. Your loop needs to be `@for (int x = 0; x < @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList.Count; x++)` in order to bind correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I see where you're coming from. The Quantity loop is to generate the number of fields because at this point nothing has been created in the DelegatesList collection. When I change to DelegatesList.Count instead of .Quantity the site returns an error Object reference not set to instance of an object as I'd imagine there isn't anything in DelegatesList

Comment: You need to populate that collection with x number of default items before you pass the model to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay makes sense. How would I link this so that the list is populated with x being the number in quantity for each orderline (being i). I've updated the post with the controller model view for reference

Comment: Sorry, but its not clear. Is the `Quantity` a input in your view, and you then want to generate a dynamic number of `DelegatesList` items based on that. And you still have not explained where the `i` variable comes from

Comment: Sorry! the view above excluded alot of code that wasn't relevant to the problem but I missed the line regarding i.

the snippet above sits in another another loop:  @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines.Count; i++)

Each OrderLine has a quantity value aka the number of places for the event they want to buy. The delegatesList needs to be dynamic to this quantity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170756/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-paul-almond).